# Unterminated string. Expected delimiter converting byte[] to Json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, api, xamarin

I'm facing an awkward error with my app that I can't figure the reason...
The complete Stack Trace is this:

```
FALHA NO POST: ProcedimentosMidias :Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path '[12].ImageBytes', line 1, position 17190742. - em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringIntoBuffer(Char quote)

em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsBytes()

em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)

em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)

em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)

em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)

em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)

em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)

em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)

em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)

em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)

em App_Services_ProcedimentosMidias.App_Services_ProcedimentosMidias_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) na C:xxxxx.xxxxx.com.brapp_servicesProcedimentosMidias.aspx.vb:linha 48
```

The scenario is that the mobile app (Xamarin/C#) transmits some images/files serializing them to byte[] and placing in the model that is converted to JSON and transmitted via HTTP.

After that, the received byte[] is deserialized back to image/file.
The serialization code in the mobile app is this:

```
public static byte[] GetFileAsByteArray(string filePath)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int read = 0;

                while((read = fis.Read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    bos.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                fis.Close();
                return bos.ToByteArray();
            }
            else
            {
                return new byte[0];
            }

            //return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        }
```

- I place the byte[] from this method on an ImageByte[] variable on my model, that is converted to Json with Newtonsoft.Json package and transmitted via HTTP POST with Refit

The same user, also got this error that I guess is related

```
POST ProcedimentosMidias retornou um erro: Data.ExceptionSystem.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error while copying content to a stream.) -> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. -> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. -> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer - End of inner exception stack trace - at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException (System.Net.Sockets.SocketError error) [0x00007] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult (System.Int16 token) [0x0001f] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask+ValueTaskSourceAsTask+<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0 (System.Object state) [0x00030] in <210883430b4a425fbc7186ded653500e>:0 - End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown - at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.InnerWrite (System.Boolean sync, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000d3] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00199] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0008b] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.StartOperation (Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+OperationType type, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0024b] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync (System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] source) [0x0015d] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask copyTask) [0x00067] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 - End of inner exception stack trace - at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask copyTask) [0x0008f] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpContentWriteStream stream, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000a0] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x012e6] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpConnection connection, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0012b] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0014b] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ba] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Object[] paramList) [0x00173] in :0 - End of inner exception stack trace - -> (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. -> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. -> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer - End of inner exception stack trace - at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException (System.Net.Sockets.SocketError error) [0x00007] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult (System.Int16 token) [0x0001f] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask+ValueTaskSourceAsTask+<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0 (System.Object state) [0x00030] in <210883430b4a425fbc7186ded653500e>:0 - End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown - at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.InnerWrite (System.Boolean sync, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000d3] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00199] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.StartOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0008b] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.StartOperation (Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+OperationType type, Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0024b] in <94ee25288e5b447880f446c994feac0b>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.WriteAsync (System.ReadOnlyMemory`1[T] source) [0x0015d] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask copyTask) [0x00067] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 - End of inner exception stack trace - at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CopyToAsyncCore (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask copyTask) [0x0008f] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendRequestContentAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpContentWriteStream stream, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000a0] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x012e6] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpConnection connection, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0012b] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0014b] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ba] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in <150dffdc6e124595ac779aab932eba71>:0 at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Object[] paramList) [0x00173] in :0 <-
```

EDIT: This is the server side code, that converts the byte[] to image

```
Dim dataStream As System.IO.Stream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream)

Dim SyncData As New List(Of Procedimentosmidias.Procedimentosmidias)
SyncData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Procedimentosmidias.Procedimentosmidias))(reader.ReadToEnd)

For Each item As Procedimentosmidias.Procedimentosmidias In SyncData
            If Not xString.IsObjectNullOrEmpty(item.ImageBytes) Then
                        Dim caminho As String = Sys.AppClient.ClientAppFiles(item.ClientId.ToString) + "/" + Path.GetFileName(item.PathMidia)
                        EquinovetMobile.ConvertBytesToImageFile(item.ImageBytes, Server.MapPath(caminho))
                        item.PathMidia = ResolveUrl(caminho)
            End If
            Datapost.Mobile.InsertUpdateSync(userToken, tabela, item, "ProcedimentoMidiaId", item.ProcedimentoMidiaId.ToString())
Next


Public Shared Function ConvertBytesToImageFile(ByVal ImageData As Byte(), ByVal FilePath As String) As Boolean
        If Not IsNothing(ImageData) Then
            Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
            Dim bw As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(fs)
            bw.Write(ImageData)
            bw.Flush()
            bw.Close()
            fs.Close()
            bw = Nothing
            fs.Dispose()
            ConvertBytesToImageFile = True
        Else
            ConvertBytesToImageFile = False
        End If
End Function
```

Can you guys help me figure this out?
Thank you very much!

Comment: The error message says `Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: "`

Comment: I think all you need to do : string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

Comment: I forgot to mention that, only 2 or 3 users are having this problem... all the other users are uploading fine... if it was the UTF8 problem, wouldn't this happen to everybody?

Comment: I added the server side code to convert byte[] to image, since I saw that the problem probably is on the server side conversion... now I don't know if the app is uploading some corrupted data or not

Comment: If the terminator is missing, that seems to imply that the request is getting truncated.  Are you maybe not flushing a buffer somewhere?